# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in XPages

Tags: java, synchronization, xpages, javabeans

We have this multi-page browser-based application in XPages. The main window contains 5 frames with different pages, a 2nd (and there may be more) contain documents, all with a different page layout. We used to run the application with "all pages in memory" (coming from R8.5.1 originally), it was lightning fast but hogging memory. We're now in the process of moving it to "one page in memory, the rest on disk".

I think the situation we have right now is this:

- all pages share the same sessionScoped bean
- page A is refreshed automatically: every minute an Ajax request is sent to fetch data
- page B happens to be serializing a HashMap at the same time
- the refresh of the first page changes the HashMap being serialized

The HashMap is an object inside the bean. Why is the bean serialized? I might be mistaken, it might just be a different HashMap that's being serialized...

Anyway, my question: how can I synchronize these actions, is there some easy way?

PS I already tried with a ConcurrentHashMap, but I got some very weird results...

Thanks for anything helpful!

Comment: You should add a small, running example showing us the issue. Right now, we can only guess. *some very weird results* is also extremely vague.

Comment: I cannot a small example, I wouldn't know how to do it. The environment is IBM/XPages, which is based on JSF. I just don't have that many clues...

Comment: What I did to overcome the problem temporarily: I changed page persistence once again, from "1 page" back to "all pages", with a maximum of 2. Now we have to see if memory still serves us...

Answer (score 1):

"Why is the bean serialized?" A sessionScoped bean would not be serialized by default. It can happen if you use a load-time binding that evaluates to the bean like ${someBean} or if its serializing the HashMap you might have referenced that in a load-time binding, like ${someBean.someHashMap} (where ${ is load-time bindings, and #{ are runtime bindings ). The results of load-time bindings are saved in the control tree, which is serialized when you're saving server-side pages on disk. The solution there would be to change those references to runtime bindings.

"how can I synchronize these actions"
There's a synchronized keyword in SSJS, see:
http://mattwhite.me/blog/2009/9/14/on-synchronization-in-xpages.html
but that can only protect the object from concurrent access in SSJS; the page state serializing won't be synchronized on the same object, so you'd still have to fix it to not-serialize the bean&HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

As always when encountering an error like this you should ask yourself why and read the documentation for the exception. This exception occurs because you modify a collection while iterating it (eg reading from it). For this exact reason Java ship with a collection implementation called CopyOfWriteList which allows writes while reading. It does this by making a new list (eg copy the pointer) when the list is written. This is great when writes are less frequent than reads. Unfortunately there is no such thing for Maps built into the jdk.

My suggestion would be to encapsulate the map and implementing a similar feature so a new map is created on new data. This would make the map immutable for readers and hence would remove the concurrent mod exception. Users that read while new data arrive would get the "old" data but it would perform much better than synchronizing access.

Hope is helps.

Comment: I'd love to make sure first which map it is, since maps are used all over the place. It could still be the viewScope map itself... I'll think about your suggestion. I could maybe isolate the few values that are put in the map, and put them in common variables. Thanks!!

Comment: You can't change the scope maps as those are created by the container. Only place you should get a concurrent mod exception from the scope maps is if you iterate the keys there which imo doesn't make sense as you know those key names. The exception only occur if you change a map while iterating over it.

Comment: My suggestion is for changing the implementation of the maps you stick in the scope maps.

Comment: I indeed save the map while iterating over its values, because the map comes from a profile document that's read while initializing the bean, and when a value is changed the map must be saved back to the profile document, field by field.